# Rewriting everything fails if only the domain (without a path) is given

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect **everything** to a different URL:

```
RewriteEngine on

# This regular expression should match all, including empty strings!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

But it's only working as long as a path is given:

- http://www.mydomain.com/x **works fine**
- http://www.mydomain.com/ **fails**
- http://www.mydomain.com **fails**

**Update:** this faulty behaviour only appears on my local setup (Win7/XAMPP/Apache/2.2.21) where everything else including all other redirects work like charme.
I tried the above code on a production server where it worked perfectly.

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have other rules as well in this .htaccess?

Comment: It's the only rule, my .htaccess is otherwise empty.
It's an Apache 2.2 running on XAMPP/Win7.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: No, doesn't help :-/ The first example does work only with Firefox though.
Chrome and Opera tell me "This website can not provide a secure connection" (translated from German).
So something must be fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Test out this code and report feedback

Comment: Thank you Diogo: I tried it, but unfortunately it brings the same result as my original method.
Now I also tried it on a different (production) server: there both variants work like charme! So it has to do with my local configuration :-( Any Idea?

Comment: saw that you're running apache 2.2 on windows server. What about your production server? Linux with apache 2.4?

Comment: Yes! Specifically Apache/2.4.27.

Comment: @Eddie since you're on windows computer with XAMPP can you please check if you have Module Apache mod_rewrite enabled? I work on linux never used XAMPP, so idk if it will be enable by default or not.

Comment: Find the “httpd.conf” file under the “conf” folder inside the Apache’s installation folder, open it and uncomment LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. Save the file and restart apache. Then it should be enabled

Comment: Yes, it's enabled, and was the whole time. Might be some internal misconfig, I'm working on the Linux test server now ;-) Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you still want to test it out, I found an article that might help you, test the first answer given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443369/mod-rewrite-not-working-for-apache-2-2-on-windows-7